# How will I export the data from listview to excel and pdf in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, listview, pdf

Good day Folks!

Can I ask for your help? :) My question is how will I export the data from listview to excel and PDF directly without using the database or crystal report. Is there a possible way that I can do that?

Thank you! :)

Kindly check for the picture in the linkbelow

http://postimg.org/image/fjcgk0oap/6226dbd8/

---

Hi Sir - I include my datasouce and the code for searching data. Kindly help me for this. Thanks!

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; database=complain; uid=root;pwd=admin1950")
con.Open() 
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_complain WHERE status=@status order by store, date_complaint DESC, time_complaint DESC" 
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", combo_status.Text)
```

Comment: And now, what is the problem? Do you have trouble retrieving the text from your database? Can you retrieve it but not insert it in excel? Can you insert it in excel but not export it to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your datasource (e.g., database connection...) once the data is available in excel, and you want to save that range to pdf, you can try this.

```
Sheets("sheetname").Range("yourrange...b1:327...").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "c:\Book1.pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Hi Sir - I include my datasouce and the code for searching data. Kindly help me for this. Thanks!


Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; database=complain; uid=root;pwd=admin1950")
                con.Open()
                Dim query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_complain WHERE status=@status order by store, date_complaint DESC, time_complaint DESC"
                Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", combo_status.Text)

Comment: @RonnMatthewMoreno Please edit your question with your code instead of putting it in a comment, this becomes unreadable...

Comment: @DrDonut Hi Sir- Kindly read my question again. Thank you all! :)

Comment: are you saying you're not able to get data into the excel sheet at the momement?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @chungtinhlakho Yes. I have data in listview and I want to export it in excel. How will I do that? Thanks!